# For what possible reason this JNI Code is not returning a correct value?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

For what possible reason this JNI Code is not returning a value nbField ?

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_morpho_morphosmart_sdk_MorphoDatabaseNative_getNbField
 (JNIEnv *i_env, jobject thisObj, jlong morphoDatabasePointerCPP, jobject nbField){

I   l_i_Ret;
UL  l_ul_NbField;

l_i_Ret = dataBase->GetNbField(l_ul_NbField);
    // l_ul_NbField is equal 2 after here

if(l_i_Ret == 0) // l_i_Ret is not null
{
    jclass longClass = i_env->GetObjectClass(nbField);
    jfieldID val = i_env->GetFieldID(longClass, "value", "J");
    if(val == NULL)
         return -899;  
    i_env->SetLongField(nbField, val, (L)l_ul_NbField);
    // nbField is an output value wich is expected to have the value 2 after here !

}

return l_i_Ret; }
```

This code result in returning 0 but nbField is empty !
***Java caller***

```
  long nbField = 0 ;
  int l_i_ret = morphoDatabase.getNbField(nbField);
    Log.d("GetNBFields","after getNBFields : "+ nbField + " r : " + l_i_ret );
```

the problem is in this part of the code,  `nbField` does not return the value of`l_ul_NbField`.

Comment: "Not working" isn't very precise...

Comment: updated, not returning the value 'nbField' ...

Comment: Show more jni? What do your make files look like? What is the build error if there is one?

Comment: the problem is in this part of the code, `nbField` does not return the value of `l_ul_NbField`.

Comment: What is the expected value and how has it been verified?  What is the resulting value, where is the java code which accesses it, and how has that been verified?

Comment: it is 2 and has been verified using Returns. The resulting value is the value I am looking for that I am not getting and which is supposed  to be 2. The code is part of biggest code in JNI, i can't put everything ...

Comment: You'll have to make a tiny example which still demonstrates the problem, and post that - **complete** native and Java code.  Please be sure to include something which logs the values from both sides to verify the mismatch.

Comment: You have to post the java code too.  And put in logging in **both** native and java code to prove that the values are or are not what you expect them to be.  Frankly it's rather unclear what the goal of your code even is.

Comment: First guess is that 'l_i_Ret' isn't zero. Have you considered that possibility? Second guess is that you're getting a JNI error which is being concealed from you by your complete lack of error checking. You need to check the result of *every* JNI operation. No if's, no buts.

Comment: 'l_i_Ret' is not null, I 've checked that.

Comment: How to log in JNI @ChrisStratton ?

Comment: I didn't ask whether it was `null`. I speculated whether it was zero. What happened when you put in the error checking I mentioned?

Comment: nothing at all ! It goes until the end like everything is okey but the value of nbField is empty ...

Answer (score 0):

the solution I found is :

```
Long nbField = new Long(0);
```

rather than `long`.